# Adjust Video Quality 360,720 etc

Tags: php, ios, iphone, video-compression, videoquality

By Using video URL's I'm playing video's in my app, now in addition I need to implement Adjust Video Quality feature because as per App requirement if there is slow internet so there would be a Quality selection options like Youtube.(144,260,320,720 etc ).I did some R&d and found there are some compression tools But didn't found that.So can anybody tell me how can I achieve this feature.

Any help will be appreciable.

Please check for more understanding

[image]

Video's are at PHP server

Comment: download video to server, convert, make it available at less quality

Comment: @Rico video's are already on server how can we compress those at specified   resolutions.

Comment: install ffmeg on your server and use shell_exec() to call it from your php file to convert

Comment: or use online converter service

Comment: http://apiv2.online-convert.com/#objects_job_output